# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'. Poetry. Amazon linux

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, python-import, python-poetry, amazon-linux

Try to run python script on ec2 instance with amazon linux os. Script has `import tqdm` line. Dependency manager - poetry. What I try to do:

1. Install python3.9
2. Install poetry
3. Upload script using ssh
4. `poetry add tqdm` and got

```
The following packages are already present in the pyproject.toml and will be skipped:

 • tqdm

If you want to update it to the latest compatible version, you can use `poetry update package`.
If you prefer to upgrade it to the latest available version, you can use `poetry add package@latest`.

Nothing to add.
```

5. `poetry install` and got

```
Installing dependencies from lock file

No dependencies to install or update

Installing the current project: backend-core (0.0.1)
```

6. `python3 importer.py` and got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/ec2-user/portal/packages/backend-core/bin/importer.py", line 6, in <module>
   from tqdm.contrib.logging import logging_redirect_tqdm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is a good idea to install / reinstall python on Linux environments.  It is part of the operating system.  I think, you can simply try to install with:

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

This worked for me on Amazon Linux 2.  I cannot reproduce the next steps: you have not provided enough [info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

If you really need to have python3.9 at the first step, try to set up a virtual environment:

1. Install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html)

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-py37_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Answer questions to accept the license terms, select location to install and init.

2. Restart your shell
3. Create virtual environment

```
conda create -n your_env_name python=3.9
conda activate your_env_name
```

4. Install `poetry` and packages you need

I could not test further, because I do not know what you do next, but hope this helps.